# How do I uninstall Black Mesa if it wasn't installed via Steam?

Tags: black-mesa

Black Mesa provides a [standalone installer](http://www.blackmesasource.com/download.html) that extracts the game to the Steam folder, so Steam can manage launching the game as well as providing the Steam Overlay in-game.

However, Steam doesn't manage uninstalling the game as it wasn't installed through Steam ([the game has been Greenlit](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=94128543) <del>but it's not yet available in the store as of Sep 2012</del> and is now [available for download via Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/362890)). How do I completely uninstall Black Mesa in this case? It seems I can just remove the `steamapps/SourceMods/BMS` folder and the shortcut from `steam/games`, then restart Steam, but I'm not sure if that covers it entirely.

Comment: Yep that will do it, the installer only adds the BMS folder to the sourcemods.

Comment: Additionally, you *could* also uninstall the Source SDKs, of course only in the case these are not needed anymore by other mods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's all there is to it. The installer is very lightweight and doesn't do anything fancy: it just handles unpacking the slightly-unusual archive file format for you, dumps all the files in the mod folder, and adds the link so Steam finds it. It doesn't scatter files across your drive or do anything like adding registry entries. Nuke the folder and remove the Steam entry and it will be like it was never there.

Comment: Good to know. I'll also get rid of the Source SDK Base 2007 files as suggested by coldcut, since Black Mesa is the only Source mod on my computer.

Comment: @Pyro I *personally* would leave it, but that's me. Only you can judge the trade off between saving disk space and maybe saving bandwidth later if you need it again. :)